# Oracle. Select data from one session but commit it to another. Is it possible?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Probably I ask for the impossible, but I'll ask anyway.

Is there an easy way to select from one `Oracle` session and then `insert`/`commit` into another?

(I guess, technically it could be done with `pl/sql` procedure calls and `PRAGMA AUTONOMUS Transactions`, but it would be a hassle)

I have the following scenario:

I run some heavy calculations and `update` / `insert into` some tables.
After the process is completed I would like to 'backup' the results
(`create table as select` or `insert into` another temp table) and then `rollback` my current session without loosing the backups.

Here is desired/expected behavior:

**Oracle 11g**

```
insert into TableA (A,B,C) values (1,2,3);

select * from TableA 

Result:    1,2,3

create table [in another session] TempA 
as select * from TableA [in this session];

rollback;

select * from TableA;

Result null
select * from TempA;

Result 1,2,3
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You could bulk collect your results into a collection and then use that via an autonomous transaction to insert (and commit) into another table.

Comment: Autonomous transaction won't help because an autonomous transaction cannot see your previous session changes. Bulk collecting into a collection, rolling back to remove the table changes, and then writing the collection into a new table might be the only solution. How difficult the code is depends on exactly how it will be used. For example, does the procedure only ever need to work for one table at a time, and will it always be for a `SELECT *` with no where clause?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to select from one Oracle session and then `insert`/`commit` into another?

Create a program in a third-party language (C++, Java, PHP, etc.) that opens two connections to the database; they will have different sessions regardless of whether you connect as different users or both the same user. Read from one connection and write to the other connection.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert your "heavy calculation" into a Oracle temp Table .

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE HeavyCalc (
  id           NUMBER,
  description  VARCHAR2(20)
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

the trick is that when you commit the transaction all rows are deleted from temporary table.

Then you first insert data into the temp table, copy the result to you backup table and commit the transaction.